# Why is my discord bot returning 'undefined' for the new guild members tag when welcoming them

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I am coding a bot in discord.js and was working on implementing a welcome DM for when a new user joins the guild. Then when I used `${member.tag}` is returned undefined, what am I doing wrong. I've been trying to figure this out for 10 minutes now and don't want this to escalate into me trying to figure it out for an hour

Code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

    member.send(`Hello, ${member.tag}`)

});
```

Comment: Apologies if this is a dumb question I'm still pretty new to js and discord.js's api so most of this is alien to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `tag` property on a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), so your code is expectedly returning `undefined`.  It does, however, exist on a [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) which you can get from the GuildMember with [`GuildMember#user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user).

**`member.user.tag`** is what you're looking for.

---

<sub>**NOTE:** The Discord.js documentation hyperlinked is for recently released v12. If your Discord.js isn't up to date, switch to the correct version at the top of the page for accurate info.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would give a go to **member.displayName**

Here is an example that I use

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

// ADD MEMBER ROLE ON JOIN, this is optional
member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Member"))

const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'arrivals')

const welcomeEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle(`New member has arrived`)
    .setColor(0x8A3F3F)
    .setDescription(`Welcome to server, ${member.displayName}!`)

channel.send({ embed: welcomeEmbed })
})
```

So in your case you can just get rid of the **const channel** and replace **channel.send** with **member.send**

Comment: Keep in mind that [`GuildMember#displayName`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=displayName) is different than a tag. If the member has a nickname set, it will be their nickname; otherwise, their username. That means no discriminator (the `#1234`) is ever included.

Comment: @madladzen there could be then other problems with your code. You should attach your whole code.

Comment: It was already answered, the problem was that I was using member.tag instead of member.user.tag